# Is there an MKSquare in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift2, mapkit

I have a bunch of lat/long coordinates and I need to draw a square polygon around each one. Each square will be a set size (e.g. 50x50) with the coordinate in the centre. I see there is a `MKCircle` class but is there an `MKSquare` equivalent (I couldn't fine one but that doesn't mean there isn't) and if there isn't, any suggestions on how this could be achieved? I have done some searching and didn't produce any solid suggestions.

I would also like to make the square 3D as in if the map is tilted it would show a height kind of like buildings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`MKPolygon`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkpolygon#) for this. Simply provide four coordinates the correct distance from your center point and the four coordinates will form a square.

Comment: So I just need to work out what the new lat long coordinates using the centre.